Manualy setting 'id' operation error probability in GenericBackendV2 doesn't work
I am trying to alter the noise probability for 'id' operation in GenericBackendV2. This is my code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import GenericBackendV2

device_backend = GenericBackendV2(num_qubits=10)
device_backend.target['id'][(0,)].error = 1
backend = AerSimulator.from_backend(device_backend)

# Create a simple circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.id(0)
circuit.measure_all()
circuit.draw('mpl')


# Transpile the circuit for the noisy basis gates
tcirc = transpile(circuit, backend)

# Execute noisy simulation and get counts
result_noise = backend.run(tcirc).result()
counts_noise = result_noise.get_counts(0)
plot_histogram(counts_noise, title="title")

This code doesn't introduce any noise on the 'id' channel. However setting error propability on 'measure' like this:
device_backend.target['measure'][(0,)].error = 1

works perfectly. Why is this?

The reason why its not working is because you are transpiling the circuit. Your circuit before transpiling looks like this:

But after you run transpile your circuit changes to this:

Notice how there is no id gate to apply the error on. The reason for this is, because id gate does nothing to the qubit, the transpiler pass will remove it so that there are less gates to run which means less error will be introduced. But if you want to apply error just use the non-transpiled circuit. So your code changes to:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import GenericBackendV2

device_backend = GenericBackendV2(num_qubits=10)
device_backend.target['id'][(0,)].error = 1
backend = AerSimulator.from_backend(device_backend)

# Create a simple circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(3)
circuit.id(0)
circuit.measure_all()
circuit.draw('mpl')

#Execute noisy simulation and get counts
result_noise = backend.run(circuit).result()  # Use the original circuit here
counts_noise = result_noise.get_counts(0)
plot_histogram(counts_noise, title="title")

This will result in a histogram which looks something like this:

Your code was working correctly for device_backend.target['measure'][(0,)].error = 1 is becasue transpile won't get rid of the measure from the circuit.
